# /bin/find: `/tmp/my_file_1': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, скрипт

Всем привет!

Существует некий сервер с centos 6 на порту и `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` . На этом сервере так же есть `apache` который создаёт кучу файлов в `/tmp/` и эти файлы надо периодически удалять, потому что сам apache иногда по каким-то причинам это не делает, для чего я запускаю по крону каждые 2 часа:

```
/bin/find /tmp -type f -user apache -group apache -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Всё вроде бы работает, но иногда, примерно 1 в сутки крон говорит мне:

```
/bin/find: `/tmp/my_file_1': No such file or directory
```

При этом этот "my_file_1" (имя взято от балды) создаётся вообще другим демоном и не принадлежит apache. Даже если добавить его в исключение `... ! -iname "*my_file_*"` - команда начинает ругаться уже на другие файлы, в этот раз принаджежащие apache.

Я не уверен, но мне кажется find в процессе работы, сначала формирует список всех файлов в директории, а потом уже начинает их фильтровать по заданным критериям, и так получается, что в эти самые милисекунды, некоторые файлы из этого списка удаляют другие демоны из-за чего у find происходит когнитивный диссонанс и он начинает материться в крон, который в свою очередь отправляет матюгальники мне в почту.

Собсно вопросы: Правильно ли я рассуждаю? И что лучше всего сделать, чтоб этого избежать не перенаправляя вывод ошибок в `/dev/null` ?

Answer (score 4):

Да, всё в принципе так и есть, сначала find читает список файлов с помощью `getdents(2)` пока не заполнится буфер, а потом применяет фильтры, в данном случае для каждого файла потребуется вызов `stat(2)`, который и возвращает ошибку, если файл был удалён со времени чтения каталога.

Специально для подавления этих ошибок у гнутого `find`'а есть опция `-ignore_readdir_race`.

В принципе, это не полностью устраняет гонку: если файл будет удалён после того, как для него вызвали `stat()`, то ругаться начнёт уже `rm`, так что стоит добавить `rm`'у ключ `-f`.

---

**Update**

Начиная с GNU findutils-4.7.0 `-delete` также принимает во внимание `-ignore_readdir_race`, так что для новых версий `find ... -ignore_readdir_race -delete` также должен работать корректно.

Comment: А с ключём `-delete` точно не будет ругаться? По-моему я его пробовал, боюсь обмануть, и это не даль положительного результата.

Comment: @nobody не могу гарантировать, но не должен... в принципе, если будет ругается, то вполне можно отписаться о баге... подразумевается, что `-ignore_readdir_race` всё равно указан...

Comment: @nobody посмотрел на `-delete`... да, в нём ошибка не подавляется... надо будет отписаться об этом в апстрим...